# Any way to remove print track count from showing up after a correct answer is inputted?

Tags: python

```
while guess_q != guess_result:
    guess_q = input("Guess away: ")
    i -= 1
    print("You have " + str(i) + " tries remaining")
    if i == 0:
        print("You lost")
        break
print("Congrats!!")
```

I just started learning Python and I manage to make a guessing game, but the problem is everytime I input the correct answer the tracker that's counting how many tries left is also printed. Is there any way to only print the tracker if the answer is still wrong and not print it when the input is correct?

Comment: You already seem to be familiar with `if` statements. Why not use one to print only when the guess was wrong?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you can simply move the line with `print("You have " ...` to after the line `if i == 0:`

Comment: Perhaps you could move the `print("You have ...` to just under the `while`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, your while loop already test if you are giving the right answer, and breaks if you don't have any chances left, so you can move the print after the break. However, if you lose, you will still print "Congrats" with your code right now.

Since you have 2 possible conditions for stoping your loop, and they should give different printed output, you could do a "while true" loop with the to breaking conditions inside:

```
i = 5
while True:
    guess_q = input("Guess away: ")
    i -= 1
    if guess_q == guess_result:
        print("Congrats!!")
        break. # If you win, breaks the loop
    if i == 0:
        print("You lost")
        break  # If you run out if trial, break the loop
    else:  # If you still have trials, print the message and keep going
        print("You have " + str(i) + " tries remaining")
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll try to modify my code to make it function more properly